# Как подключить базу данных mysql к сайту на Tilda?

Tags: mysql, tilda

У меня есть база данных `mysql` и сайт на tilda. База данных находится на сервере. Могу я как-то их связать?

Answer (score 1):

можно подключить через Webhook. Настройки сайта → Формы → Приемщик Webhook → Поставить ссылку на сторонний скрипт передачи данных. Подробнее: http://help-ru.tilda.ws/formswebhook

Или, если вы хотите, чтобы обращение к стороннему сервису было напрямую, то можно подключить скрипт таким способом: http://help-ru.tilda.ws/formsscript